# jQuery $(document).ready() not firing after window.location.href

Tags: jquery

I have two pages, on the first page after an event happens I change the location of the page by using:

```
window.location.href = "/pageb";
```

On the second page, I have a document ready event that doesn't fire when coming from the page above.  The ready event works when the page is browsed to normally.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert('ready');      
});
```

I am using the google ajax cdn to include jquery on my pages.  I'm stumped...

Comment: it should fire the ready function, just make sure that the jquery is loading successfully

Comment: yes be sure javascript is not broken ... use firebug if not yet using

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, the effect is the same on all browsers and I confirmed jquery is loading using firebug.

Comment: Could you show the code because I'm stumped.

Comment: Who up votes these vague questions that have way too little detail to fix the problem. Either paste the full code, give some links to your pages or replicate the issue at jsbin.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, though I'm using jQuery (1.4.1) from my server, and I use :

```
window.location = "/index.html";
```

I don't see why it would change anything, but maybe you could try anyways ?