# Print other page with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have page with a print button. From this page I will print a reportpage by an AJAX call. I've made a reportpage and with jquery the page will be printed when I call that page directly in the browser. In this page I used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   window.print();
});
```

So this works! But when I call the printpage with an AJAX call from the other page the print command won't fire:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'pages/reportPage.php',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
        id:id
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('False!');
    },
    success:function(data){
      //alert(data);
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    }
  });
```

When I display the data (alert(data)), I see the code of the reportpage, so the reportpage is successfull called.

Does anybody knows why this won't work with an AJAX call?

Comment: Printing is a client-side activity and you're calling a PHP script on the server-side that does not render on the client.

Comment: You're successfully making the AJAX call, but you don't do anything with the result.  Instead you just redirect the user to `index.php`.  If you want the browser to print the page then you at least need to render that page in the browser.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707251/how-do-i-print-different-page-using-javascript-jquery-ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365220/jquery-document-ready-not-firing-after-window-location-href and try window.location instead.